# Simple CSS modifications with Angular-Material

Tags: html, css, angular-material

it's with a sense of mild despair that I am asking for help with this, but I cannot seem to change the positioning of a button relative to some input boxes ?!?!?!?! I am using Angular Material, and have created this:

[image: lOGIN Bar]

Obviously, I would like the sign In button to vertically align with the input fields, but nothing I have tried will make it budget without moving the other elements. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="navbar">
    <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding>
      <form ng-submit="submitLoginForm()" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <md-input-container style="width:150px;">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input ng-model="loginForm.email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input ng-model="loginForm.password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-raised" type="submit">
          <span ng-show="!loginForm.loading">Sign in</span>
          <span ng-show="loginForm.loading" class="fa fa-spinner"></span>
          <span ng-show="loginForm.loading">Signing in...</span>
        </md-button>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
      </form>
    </md-content>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    height:75px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please create a snippet that replicates the issue.

Comment: As a quick note, the `md-input-container` automatically adds space at the bottom for error messages. This is probably part of the issue. You can change that by adding a class to your input container and the CSS `.md-errors-spacer { min-height: 0px; }` or just make it `display: none`. We're working to make inline form elements easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
 <md-input-container style="width:150px;">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input ng-model="loginForm.email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input ng-model="loginForm.password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button class="md-raised" type="submit">
      <span ng-show="!loginForm.loading">Sign in</span>
      <span ng-show="loginForm.loading" class="fa fa-spinner"></span>
      <span ng-show="loginForm.loading">Signing in...</span>
    </md-button>
</div>
```

try to use `div` tag to wrap each row in you form and then you can apply [layout-align](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment) attribute to that